# Object Generation, Updating and Deletion

Tags: java, arrays, performance, for-loop, libgdx

I am currently creating a game in JAVA on Android Studio for release on Android and IOS. Our libGDX library dependencies include Box2D and FreeType. The game is designed with the intention that the user will be frequently interacting with a multitude of objects (Individual Box2D bodies) on the screen (via touch input). A maximum of 30 objects are present at any given time. The current version of the game stores objects in an array and destroys them once they’ve been ‘scored’ or ‘lost’ (A loss occurs when an object transcends the length of the screen without being acted upon). As the game progresses, objects are generated more quickly and the speed of objects increases. We were experiencing some lag as the game progressed and believe it is due to having ‘for’ loops used to update, render and check to see if the object has been destroyed. With up to 30 shapes potentially, we felt this was an inefficient approach but are not sure what the alternative is. Here is an example of the structure:

```
// Updates shapes in the array and removes them from the array if necessary
for (int i = 0; i < randomShapes.size(); i++) {
    randomShapes.get(i).update(delta);
    if(randomShapes.get(i).isDestroyed()) {
        randomShapes.get(i).dispose();
        randomShapes.remove(i);
    }
}
```

We attempted to implement a pools data structure. After reading online that pools should be used for objects that are frequently added/deleted. Our team figured that this was the correct approach and would solve our lag issues. Although pools make initializing a new object less expensive (Since the initialization only occurs once) we still experienced lag (Possibly even worse than before) and were still unable to figure out a way to eliminate ‘for’ loops. Here is an example of the structure:

```
// Updates shapes in the array and removes them from the array if necessary
for (RandomShape shape: activeShapes) {
    shape.update(delta);
    if(shape.isDestroyed()) {
        activeShapes.removeValue(shape, true);
        //activeShapes.removeIndex(i);
        shapePool.free(shape);
        System.out.println("SHAPES AVAILABLE: " + shapePool.getFree());
        System.out.println("MAX SHAPES: " + shapePool.max);
    }
}
```

For games that deal with needing to update multiple unique objects that are being destroyed and added every second, what is a more efficient way to run through the array or pool that does not involve implementing a ‘for’ loop that constantly cycles through the elements?

Comment: Instead of brute force, I think using any broadphase works better, but since you are using Box2D, I think you should be using a `btDynamicTree` structure. Did you profile your application?

Comment: What are activeShapes or randomShapes? Since you're removing inside the list, maybe use a LinkedList, and remove directly from the iterator you use to go through the list.

Comment: measure what's slow, otherwise you're just guessing. nothing wrong with the above code.

Comment: @JP Moresmau. activeShapes and randomShapes are ArrayLists of a RandomShape class that extends sprite. RandomShape creates one of 16 possible shapes (Along with their bodies and fixtures).

Comment: @Barodapride What is a good way to measure what's slow, is there a good guide online as to how to troubleshoot the bottleneck?

Comment: @Sri Harsha Chilakapati why is btDynamicTree a better alternative to implementing a broadphase structure? Or is btDynamicTree a form of broadphase structure. Not entirely sure what it means to profile your application (Help me out here).

Comment: Have you profiled this? Find out what method is causing the lag. 30 is a very tiny number of objects.

Comment: Are you calling `world.destroyBody(bodyToDestroy)` when you are done with them?

Comment: use TimeUtils from libgdx to measure the current time anywhere in your code. Capture the time when a method starts to when it ends. Alternatively, use a profiler. You are probably doing something really silly to have bad lag (like creating objects in the render method).

Comment: @Tenfour04 By profiling do you mean looking at the graphs of CPU, GPU and Memory usage in Android Studio?

Comment: @Barodapride When you mention creating objects in render method... currently we are calling a method called populateGame() from within the render method that generates the objects.

Comment: @Menno Gouw Yes we are calling `world.destroyBody(bodyToDestroy)` when we are finished with them.

Comment: Yes, or use jvisualvm with the desktop build.

Comment: @TheWaveCarver Sorry for not being clear, `btDynamicTree` is a form of broadphase that Box2D uses internally, which produces very good performance. Since your bodies are very low in number, I wondered why. The solution is to profile your application, run it with tools like JVisualVM and profile the memory and cpu, you'll learn where are objects created at high density, and also which methods are taking so much time to execute, so you can optimize it out. Without that, it will be a pure guess.